# Как вывести в ASP.NET данные из столбцов таблицы содержащих(допускающих ) значение NULL?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net

У меня есть база данных SolarSystem, созданная в  SQL Server Managment Studio. В ней  есть таблица  Planets . Для того чтобы вывести на экран все данные из этой таблицы , я создал в папке Models класс  Planet и в нем определил свойства  . Написал все остальное  и запустил. У меня вышла такая ошибка:"InvalidOperationException:
The 'Volume' property on 'Planet' could not be set to a 'System.Double' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'System.Single'. " Читал на англоязычном  stackoverflow ,что это оттого что в SQL тип FLOAT  соответствует типу  double в C#, а не типу float .Переделал все свойства типа  float на double и опять запустил. Выскочило вот это :
System.Data.ConstraintException: "The 'Volume' property on 'Planet' ' could not be set to a 'null' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'System.Double'. " Я сильно подозреваю ,что это оттого,  что у меня в таблице это самое 'Volume' допускает значение NULL (И есть там строки, содержащие   NULL-значение в этом поле.) Читал такое, что вроде для решения этой проблемы надо установить атрибут CanBeNULL то ли над свойством, то ли под ним. Делал и так и так, весь этот атрибут подчеркивает красным.   Вопрос мой ,наверное ,страшно нубский, но я очень прошу вас объяснить мне,  как вывести в  ASP.NET  данные из  база данных ,столбцы которой  содержат( и допускают) значение  NULL . Весь код, который я тут буду приводить дальше, студия красным не  подчеркивает, и вообще сейчас ничего красным не  подчеркивает.
Класс  Planet:

```
 using System;

 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;

 namespace SolarSystem.Models
 {
public class Planet
 {
    public int PlanetId { get; set; }

    public double Volume { get; set; }

    public double Weight { get; set; }
    public double Diameter { get; set; }
    public decimal DistanceEarth { get; set; }
    public decimal DistanceSun { get; set; }
    public double RotationSun { get; set; }
    public double Rotation { get; set; }

    public int QuantitySatellites { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
}
```

Класс SolarSystemContext

```
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace SolarSystem.Models
{
public class SolarSystemContext: DbContext
{

    public DbSet<Planet> Planets { get; set; }

}
}
```

Класс HomeController ```C#

```
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using SolarSystem.Models;

namespace SolarSystem.Controllers
{
 public class HomeController : Controller

{
    SolarSystemContext db = new SolarSystemContext();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Planets);
    }


    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)

    {
        db.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
}
```

Представление куда должны выводиться данные CSHTML

```
@{


Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Книжный магазин</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <h3>Распродажа книг</h3>
    <table>
        @foreach (SolarSystem.Models.Planet p in Model)
        {
        <tr>
            <td><p>@p.PlanetId</p></td>
            <td><p>@p.Name</p></td>
            <td><p>@p.QuantitySatellites</p></td>
            <td><p>@p.Volume</p></td>
        </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>
```

Если что,  то NuGet я уже в проект импортировал, и я работаю на  SQL Server Express Edition, Visual Studio  2017   и MVC4 . Буду также благодарен какой-нибудь ссылке на тему  моего вопроса(Можно англоязычную.).

Comment: `double?` [Nullable Type in C#](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-nullable-types)

Answer (score 0):

Для того чтобы сделать  свойство (Или переменную) допускающим значение  NULL, надо просто поставить ? после имени типа.

```
        public double ? Volume
```

Ссылка  в комментарии Denis Rubashkin в самую точку.
Вообще этот знак "?" после имени типа означает  упрощенную запись объявления типа Nullable. К примеру, переменную  Volume можно было бы объявить и так:

```
  public Nullable <double>    Volume
```

Тип Nullable может принимать все значения, которые может принимать тип ,заключенный в угловые скобки + значение null. Также стоит отметить, что если вы хотите приравнять тип  Nullable к не- Nullable типу, то это следует делать так:

```
double ? d;


double j=d?? 0;
```

Эта запись означает, что в случае  если d  примет null-значение ,тогда j    примет значение 0.